# Toolbar not showing message with Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/ph_bg"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Profile_Activity"
 >
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/profile_appbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/theme_color"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

Activity Code

`profile_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.profile_appbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(profile_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        profile_toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font       color='#ffffff'>AppTitle</font>"));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

I  have  toolbar  in  Scroll view but  its  not  showing  title 
in  white color I  have  the  above  code in activity

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest file
`<activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: It  doesnot  work